# Emulator does not open up when running program in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

## Overview

I went to run my program in Android Studio using an emulator, but after I completed the process, the emulator would not open up. Several errors were shown in the Event Log when I tried to run it.

## Errors

```
7:41 PM Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3, requires minimum version 4
7:41 PM Emulator: No accelerator found.
7:41 PM Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
7:41 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Images

[There were several errors in the Event Log as shown in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3RLE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) a minimum version **of 4** (currently, *it is 3*) or goto:

`SDK manager` > `Extras` > `Intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer)` and update to the latest version.

This happens because it needs a minimum version of 4 but you already installed version 3 so, updating will solve the issue.